# CRA PWA installed to home screen on iOS 13 does not update?

Tags: ios, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I have created a pwa with `create react app method`. I installed it to home screen of iPhone with `iOS 13`. Then I made an update to the app and deployed it. But app installed on iPhone home screen does not update. The home screen app updates if I open the app first in Safari. Also the app updates if I clear the cache of Safari.

In Android everything is working like it should be and the home screen installed on Android device updates automatically.

I don't know if I should provide you with some code, if you want to see some, please tell me what. I have found some talk about this and it might be something to do with new lifecycle of pwa/home screen apps updated in `iOS 12`. But also there was talk that it should be fixed in `iOS 13`. So I'm not sure where should I start to look the problem.

Comment: I could solve this issue with a combination of this script: https://gist.github.com/kawazoe/fa3b5a3c998d16871ffb9e2fd721cb4b and also, adding SKIP_WAITING as explained in one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904430/how-to-implement-skipwaiting-with-create-react-app The solution is not ideal, but does the job on IOS. Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.